# Creating powerpoint from multiple Excel files using Python

Tags: python

I am working on creating a pptx file from multiple XL files using Python.
Each XL file has multiple worksheets. Each worksheet has few table(3-4) and few graphs(3-4). Now the final output pptx has a fixed template and i need to get these graphs and headings in the final file.

Please advise if there is any available code that i can refer.

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: This is not Q &A site. Show us what you tried and where you are getting error...

Comment: But he was asking a problem where he can't start, he can ask question like that question. Correct me, If I am wrong?

Comment: [python for making PPT](http://pbpython.com/creating-powerpoint.html), I think this would be useful.

Comment: @kvk30 i think instead of giving available code we should suggest him to understand need and effort that he has done...ok.

Comment: @Narendra This _is_ a Q&A site. However, the OP must demonstrate a research effort, post their code, and ask specific questions.

Comment: @kvk30- Thanks for the link

Comment: @Narendra- This is Q&A site and who ever posts here needs guidance, some are experts in their field and some are beginners who need understanding to start working on a concept...